# Laravel Spatie Browsershot on Windows: works in console, not in browser

Tags: node.js, laravel, browsershot

I can't wrap my head around the following issue. I have a development environment on Windows 11.

I try to get Spatie's Browsershot working on Windows and keep getting errors about node not being recognized as a internal or external program.

However, when I run just "node -v" from any location in a CMD-shell, I everytime see the version number. So, path vars are set right I guess. I use the latest version of Laravel and Browsershot.

When I execute this simple Tinker script through "php artisan tinker" I do see the desired html:

```
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
$a = new Browsershot();
$a->url('https://www.ad.nl')->bodyHtml();
```

When I run this via the browser (using routes/web.php), I get errors:

```
Route::get('/a', function () {
  $a = new Browsershot();
  $a->url('https://www.ad.nl')->bodyHtml();
});
```

Errors:

```
2022-12-02 11:01:48] local.ERROR: The command "node ^"C:^\dev^\projects^\test^\vendor^\spatie^\browsershot^\src/../bin/browser.js^" ^"^{^\^"url^\^":^\^"https:^\/^\/www.ad.nl^\^",^\^"action^\^":^\^"content^\^",^\^"options^\^":^{^\^"args^\^":^[^],^\^"viewport^\^":^{^\^"width^\^":800,^\^"height^\^":600^}^}^}^"" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: C:\dev\projects\test\public

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Exception\\ProcessFailedException(code: 0): The command \"node ^\"C:^\\dev^\\projects^\\test^\\vendor^\\spatie^\\browsershot^\\src/../bin/browser.js^\" ^\"^{^\\^\"url^\\^\":^\\^\"https:^\\/^\\/www.ad.nl^\\^\",^\\^\"action^\\^\":^\\^\"content^\\^\",^\\^\"options^\\^\":^{^\\^\"args^\\^\":^[^],^\\^\"viewport^\\^\":^{^\\^\"width^\\^\":800,^\\^\"height^\\^\":600^}^}^}^\"\" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: C:\\dev\\projects\\test\\public

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.
```

Does anybody got a clue where the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

For problem "'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command", you can set node path explicitly.

https://spatie.be/docs/browsershot/v2/requirements#content-custom-node-and-npm-binaries

Example:

Browsershot::url('https://google.com')->setNodeBinary('PATH %~dp0;%PATH%;')->setNpmBinary('PATH %~dp0;%PATH%;');

Make sure your node register on your PATH.